# Problems installing/compiling DBD::mysql on OpenSuSE 10

Tags: perl, opensuse, dbd, mysql

I am getting a bunch of compile errors when I try to install the MySQL DBD::mysql Perl library. I am trying to install this library on OpenSuse linux (SUSE Linux Enterprise server 10 (x86_64) version 10, patch level 4)
The install fails when trying to compile dbdimp.h. There are hundreds of complile errors but I have reason to believe they all stem from the first 3:

```
dbdimp.h:23:49: error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
dbdimp.h:24:45: error: mysqld_error.h: No such file or directory
dbdimp.h:26:49: error: errmsg.h: No such file or directory
```

I believe that the reason I am getting the errors above is that I have no MySql Client installed. I do not know how to install mysql client (I believe I am supposed to get some version of libmysqlclient).

I am brand new to opensuse and vaguely familar with installing packages on Linux in general have used yum, yast, apt-get on ubuntu + centOS previously but the only package manager tools that seem to be on OpenSuse 10 are rpm and zypper. I have not managed to install the required mysql client using either of these. If anyone knows how to install MySql Client to resolve my issue I would greatly appreciate any recomendations

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to install MySQL or the MySQL client libraries, either through your system's package manager or by following the installation instructions from the source code.

It sounds like your question is really "How do I install MySQL on OpenSuse", which would be more appropriate for one of the other StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this ***to a point***. In my original question, I stated that I had tried using YAST but that it had not worked. In fact, I did not fully explore the YAST install option but when I did, I managed to download install the required librarys by following an article I found (http://adminramble.com/install-mysql-yast/#chitika_close_button)
I was able to open the YAST GUI in the terminal window (not an X-window display) and navigate through the "software management" section wherein I was able to do a search for MySql. Amoung the search results were mysql client libraries, which I then selected and hit "Accept". The installation started and completed successully.

In order to complile the PERL DBD::mysql module, I had to create a new makefile with the ccflags specified so that the header files could be found:

```
perl Makefile.PL --cflags -I/usr/include/mysql
```

I say "to a point" at the top of this comment because I then ran into further problems compiling but my original issue posted has been partially resolved and getting this far may help someone else who is experiencing the same problem. Will update if I get a solution to the compile problem.